# Add a char to the beginning and end of each line in a file

Tags: python, readfile, writefile

I have a text file that each line contains exactly one word. I want update the file by attaching a char to the beginning and end of each word in each line. Here is my code in Python:

```
appendText='_'
names=open("name.txt",'r')
updatedNames=open("name2.txt",'a')
for name in names:
  updatedNames.write(appendText+name+appendText)
updatedNames.close()
```

But the problem is this code add the `_` to the end of line after the `\n` char. In other words, the output looks like this:

```
_Name
_
```

`_Name` followed by an `enter` and then in the next line there another `_`. I want to both `_` to be in the same line:

```
_Name_
```

Comment: Your example does not fit to your description: `*` and `_` are mixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove the newline and then add it back:

```
appendText='_'
names=open("name.txt",'r')
updatedNames=open("name2.txt",'a')
for name in names:
  # Python3.5 or earlier:
  # updatedNames.write(appendText + name.rstrip() + appendText + '\n')
  updatedNames.write(f'{appendText}{name.rstrip()}{appendText}\n')
updatedNames.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip) to get rid of that `\n`:

```
appendText = '_'
with open("name.txt", 'r') as names:
    with open("name2.txt", 'a') as updatedNames:
        for name in names:
            updatedNames.write(appendText + name.rstrip() + appendText + '\n')
```

And use the [context manager](http://eigenhombre.com/2013/04/20/introduction-to-context-managers/) to open your text files.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
append_text = "_"
with open("name.txt") as f:
    buff = []
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
             buff.append("%s%s%s"% (append_text,line.strip(),append_text))
    updatedNames=open("name2.txt",'w')
    updatedNames.write("\n".join(buff))
    updatedNames.close()
```

empty lines will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the \n automatically with readlines() after you opened the file:

```
mylist = names.readlines()
newstring = []
for word in list:
    newstring += appendText+word+appendText+'\n'
```

then print this to your file